# how do I show the green box in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am coding for a website, but I have came across a problem, I can't seem to get the green box to show. Please can you help me?

Please visit here to see my code: http://jsfiddle.net/9UkXe/g

```
#top_box
{
position: relative;
background:#0F3;
top:0%;
left:70%;
min-width: 90%;
max-width: 90%;
z-index:5;
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Your box has no height setted and no content; so it's 0.

Comment: You haven't defined the `height` and your positioning is very very weird

Answer (score 2):

Put content in the box or set its `height` property:

```
#top_box {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00FF33;
    height: 20px;
    left: 70%;
    max-width: 90%;
    min-width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9UkXe/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add some text to it [check your updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9UkXe/1/). Blockelements don't always appear when they're empty.

```
<div id="top_box">text</div>

<div class="background">text</div>
```